# Chrome not reloading object tag after linking to nonexistent file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, object-tag

I have the following index.html. The objective of the javascript below is to reload the `#obj` element's data tag, so that it can display multiple images. However, it is possible that one of the images I link the buttons to doesn't exist (in this case, `#2`).

```js
function updateObject(evt) {
    var id = evt.currentTarget.id;
    var object = document.getElementById("obj");

    if (id == "1") {
          object.setAttribute("data","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg")
    }
    else {
        object.setAttribute("data", "file/that/doesnt/exist")
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <   document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click", updateObject, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="1">button1</button>
        <button id="2">button2</button>
        <object id="obj" style='width: 100px'></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I expect to happen in the following script is this:

- The user presses button1, sees apple
- User presses button2, sees nothing
- User presses button1, sees apple

However, the third step in that doesn't happen - when I try to reload the object's data after linking to a nonexistent file, it stays blank.

As far as I've been able to gather, this happens in Chrome, and for me works in Safari. I must use the object tag, or some other method that allows for interactive SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution you could possibily do is to remove and add the node itself to force a hard reset

```
var clone = object.cloneNode();
var parent = object.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(object);
parent.appendChild(clone);
```

```js
function updateObject(evt) {
  var id = evt.currentTarget.id;
  var object = document.getElementById("obj");

  if (id == "1") {
    object.setAttribute("data", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg")
    var clone = object.cloneNode();
    var parent = object.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(object);
    parent.appendChild(clone);
  } else {
    object.setAttribute("data", "file/that/doesnt/exist")
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
  document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click", updateObject, false);
}
```

```html
<button id="1">button1</button>
<button id="2">button2</button>
<object id="obj" style='width: 100px'></object>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the tag to an `<img>` and setting the "src" attribute.

```js
function updateObject(evt) {
    var id = evt.currentTarget.id;
    var object = document.getElementById("obj");

    if (id == "1") {
          object.setAttribute("src","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg")
    }
    else {
        object.setAttribute("src", "file/that/doesnt/exist")
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <   document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click", updateObject, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="1">button1</button>
        <button id="2">button2</button>
        <img id="obj" style='width: 100px'></img>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't do this, since my SVG needs to be interactive. The best way I've found to do this is with the object tag.

Answer (score 1):

I provide a sample which helps you to solve your problem by making a fake request to that URL.

Chrome does it to inform. Even if you handle `onerror` correctly with correct error handling with `try-catch` and every trick with a `void` or `( )` that is told to prevent error - **you can not fix it**. It is out of Javascript control.

```js
function updateObject(evt) {
    var id = evt.currentTarget.id;
    var object = document.getElementById("obj");

    if (id == "1") {
            object.setAttribute("data","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg");
    }
    else {
      var request;
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
          request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      else
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      request.open('GET', 'file/that/doesnt/exist', false);
      request.send();
      // the object request will be actually modified
      if (request.status === 404) {
          alert("The file you are trying to reach is not available.");
      } 
      else
      {
          object.setAttribute("data", "file/that/doesnt/exist");
      }
 
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <   document.getElementsByTagName("button").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("button")[i].addEventListener("click", updateObject, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="1">button1</button>
        <button id="2">button2</button>
        <object id="obj" style='width: 100px'></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

But notice that it will only work on the same origin. For another host, you will have to use a server-side language to do that, which you will have to figure it out by yourself.